# scoverage: Combine Coverage from test and it:test

Tags: scala, sbt, code-coverage, scoverage

I splitted my Unit- and Integration-Tests with a Filter:

```
  lazy val FunTest = config("it") extend Test

  def funTestFilter(name: String): Boolean = name endsWith "Spec"

  def unitTestFilter(name: String): Boolean = name endsWith "Test"

  ...
  testOptions in Test := Seq(Tests.Filter(unitTestFilter)),
  testOptions in FunTest := Seq(Tests.Filter(funTestFilter)),
  ...
```

So I can do something like that:

`sbt clean coverage test dockerComposeUp it:test dockerComposeStop coverageReport`

Sadly that kills all my Coverage, only the generated `BuildInfo` has a Coverage.

Using only `sbt clean coverage test coverageReport` or `sbt clean coverage it:test coverageReport` work as expected.

The whole project can be found here: https://github.com/pme123/play-binding-form

scoverage Version: `1.5.1`

Comment: Have you tried `sbt clean coverage test it:test coverageReport` without the docker stuff?

Comment: Same problem, maybe it is relevant that this is a sub-module, like: `sbt clean coverage server/test server/it:test coverageReport`

Comment: Please remove `sbt-buildinfo` plugin. If it will work (it works for me) I will explain, what is happening during your build.

Comment: @GrzegorzSlowikowski: you are right - without `sbt-buildinfo` it works

Comment: @GrzegorzSlowikowski to promised me an explanation;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

SBT supports incremental compilation, but Scoverage does not support it. Scoverage clears instrumentation information before compilation starts and starts instrumentation process from scratch every time. Compilation of a subset of all classes with Scoverage enabled will result in wrong coverage reports.

In this case `sbt-buldinfo` plugin is enabled in `server` module. It registers source generator, which is executed before every compilation and generates `server/target/scala_2.12/src_managed/main/sbt-buildinfo/BuildInfo.scala` file.

SBT BuildInfo plugin is smart enough to regenerate this file only when its content changes, but since `BuildInfoOption.BuildTime` is included in `buildInfoOptions` setting,
this file is regeneraged before every compilation.

When it comes to compilation process, compiler finds one modified file (`BuildInfo.scala`) every time and starts incremental compilation of this one file. Scoverage clears its previous instrumentation information and saves only information about `BuildInfo.scala` file.

In case of execution like `sbt clean coverage test dockerComposeUp it:test dockerComposeStop coverageReport` the first compilation process is part of `test` task, and the second one `it:test` task. That's why there is no problem, when they are used separately.

Docker has nothing to do with our problem.

To fix the problem you have to prevent from `BuildInfo.scala` file regeneration on every compilation, at least when coverage is enabled.
I did it by modifying `project/Settings.scala` file in this way:

```
  private lazy val buildInfoSettings = Seq(

    buildInfoKeys := Seq[BuildInfoKey](name, version, scalaVersion, sbtVersion),

    buildInfoOptions ++= { if (coverageEnabled.value) Seq() else Seq(BuildInfoOption.BuildTime) }, // <-- this line was changed
    buildInfoOptions += BuildInfoOption.ToJson,

    buildInfoPackage := "pme123.adapters.version"
  )
```

`buildInfoOptions` does not include `BuildTime` option when coverage is turned on.

It doesn't look elegeant, but it works. You can probably find better way.

Answer (score 5):

instead of having different buildinfo objects depending on the phase, which could lead to compilation errors, you can use your own build time.

```
lazy val buildTime: SettingKey[String] = SettingKey[String]("buildTime", "time of build")

ThisBuild / buildTime := ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toString

buildInfoKeys :=
  Seq[BuildInfoKey](
    name,
    version,
    scalaVersion,
    sbtVersion,
    buildTime
  )
```

This should resolve this issue.
I have this configuration in a project of mine because I wanted a better control over the way the date is formatted, and I don't have the same issue