# Play / sbt: What are these 2 Scala sources that are always compiled on when restarting on Code change

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

Whenever I change code and Play does a restart, it always compiles 2 Scala sources, like:

```
[info] Compiling 2 Scala sources to /Users/mpa/dev/myplayproject/server/target/scala-2.13/classes ...
```

Only after that the sources I changed compiles.

*What are these 2 Sources?*

*Is there a way this can be avoided?*

Comment: Iam just guessing here. May be its routes file which is one.

Comment: Try to switch into verbose mode by entering `debug` in SBT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the tip of *@cbley* I found the problematic class:

`BuildInfo.scala` from the *sbt-buldinfo Plugin*. By default on every `compile` it creates a new timestamp, which then causes a recompile of `BuildInfo.scala`.

I actually had a similar problem with *scoverage* - see here: [scoverage: Combine Coverage from test and it:test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54349427/scoverage-combine-coverage-from-test-and-ittest)

Adding the accepted answer from there fixed the problem:

```
lazy val buildTime: SettingKey[String] = SettingKey[String]

("buildTime", "time of build")

ThisBuild / buildTime := ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC).toString

buildInfoKeys :=
  Seq[BuildInfoKey](
    name,
    version,
    scalaVersion,
    sbtVersion,
    buildTime
  )
```